# WooCommerce Migration Issues

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I recently migrated a WordPress site (from one domain to another on the same server) and am now having some issues with WooCommerce. When the "Proceed to Checkout" button is clicked, it says the page is not found and my old domain is in the URL bar.

The cart is obviously still linked to the checkout on my old domain - can I somehow link this button to the checkout on my new domain with PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try going to `Admin > Settings > Permalinks` and resaving them, might just need to be regenerated.

Comment: Figured it out.

I searched and replaced all instances of the old domain in my localhost.sql file, dropped all tables in my database and then imported the modified file.

Comment: That was going to be my next suggestion :p I wrote a plugin that (mostly) deals with this (doesn't work 100% on options/meta values) http://justin.ag/technology/wordpress/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-plugin-wp-server-migration/